# Wrong format on postal code after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, perl, validation, google-chrome

I have on my website a simple form where the user enters personal information to register as a new user.

My problem is that in some cases the postal code allows illegal characters even though i have  a JavaScript validation on the onkeyup event of my input-tag. This doesn't happen often but still happens.

In Sweden the standard postal code is a 5 digit number and my validation checks for input of illegal characters and then in my submit validation checks against the length before allowing submit of the form.

Example code

```
function check_Postal()
{
  document.RegisterForm.Postal.value = document.RegisterForm.Postal.value.replace(/[\^0-9]/g,"");
  if (document.RegisterForm.Postal.value.length == $clientProfileField{'PostalnrMax'})
  {
    document.RegisterForm.Postal.className="ClientprofileFieldOK";
  }
}
```

`PostalnrMax` is `5` for this example.

The way you normally write a postal code in Sweden is `XYZ AB`.

My problem is that some of my users postal codes are written to the database as `XYZ A`.
In the three last occurrences, the users have been using Chrome. I've tried to recreate the problem but have been unsuccessful. I'm assuming that the problem is that the users somehow enter their postal code as you normally would (`XYZ AB`) and my validation against length cuts off the last character.

So my question is, how are the users able to enter a faulty postal code? When i try it, it replaces space immediately with `""`. Has it something to do with Chrome autofill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your `$clientProfileField{'PostalnrMax'}` variable supposed to be ? Do you actually check the value of the class to be `"ClientprofileFieldOK"` before submitting ?

If you say it works on your machine, my guess would simply be that some users bypass the javascript (browser incompatibility elsewhere in your code, or simply no JS support). If you know what browsers your clients use, try to run your code on these.

Comment: $clientProfileField{'PostalnrMax'} is 5 in the example. The className set is mainly for graphic purposes. Yeah my guess has been some sort of JS bypass but i've been unable to verify it. Tested it on IE/Chrome/Safari/FF and still been unable to recreate the problem.

Comment: What proportion of entries have a bad postal code ? Can you show me your entire HTML + JS code ?

Comment: Since 23 sept 2012 i've had 16 faulty entries. In that period around 300k have registered. So it's a small number but still :)

Comment: 0.005% seems like a good proportion of users who don't have javascript support, maybe because they use old mobile browsers. If you don't have a server-side validation, this is perfectly plausible.